# Why I don't get an answer?

Tags: discussion, unanswered-questions

I have my two questions pending, don't know why no one is answering. Only comments don't lead to any conclusion! Reading comments and checking if it is right or not and at the end there's no answer, it becomes only a discussion, instead of getting a good answer in **Answer Section**.

This are my questions:
[Rendering without material when executed from command prompt](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/131134/rendering-without-material-when-executed-from-command-prompt)
[How to make forced Smoke simulation like spray?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/132832/how-to-make-forced-smoke-simulation-like-spray)

I too answer to the questions which I know... and also expect that when I ask, I will too get an answer from someone. But nothing happens, I am stuck, and I will be stucked for longer time, by finding any other options!

Comment: read also [What should I do if no one answers my question?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/help/no-one-answers)

Comment: The smoke question shows very little effort, by playing with the settings for smoke simulation you should be able to do this. Include in the question what have you tried that hasn't worked. There are tons of question on smoke.

Comment: Hi Yash, have you progressed on your efforts of the second question? Please update it or answer it yourself! This was the valuable advice of the answer you received below. Please help this site grow, by participating and adding not only good questions, but also answer. Even an edit to the question with new findings can help others who are searching for the same solution.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Well maybe nobody knows the answer to your question. You said it yourself, you answer questions that you know the answer to. One of your questions is about rendering using the CLI. There isn't a lot of artists that use the CLI to render, hence the lack of answers. You could try to promote your question by offering a bounty or sharing it through social media. If you still don't get an answer, ask in another forum or IRC and when you find the solution, come back and **answer your own question**.

As for your second question, let me quote ParallelMayhem's comment to your question:

> It probably requires masses of tweaking.

Sometimes the effect you are looking for is achieved by spending a lot of time tweaking and tuning parameters. You have to understand that users won't spend most of their free time trying to achieved the effect you are after. Often you will only be given suggestions and pointers, it is your job to find the setup that replicates the effect based on user's input. And again, when you do, come back and **answer your own question.**

Comment: That's my answer, okay I will look after that.

Comment: +1 For the last sentence of each paragraph. I will repeat it again =) Yash, have you progressed in your search, **please update your question or add an answer**.